# Angular5 + DotnetCore 2.1 - How to convert dateTime?

Tags: angular, .net-core, automapper

I have a problem handling date in angular, I got a datetime from server (using ASP.NET Core 2.1) like : "2018-07-29T06:31:41.57547" but actually I just need the date only without time like "2018-07-29". This caused my  wont show the date in my form.

Should I use AutoMapper to map all datetime to string first or could I just convert to date in my angular ? or any other solutions ?

Comment: Did u try this from your api  serverDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: I will convert in my api if it would be difficult to do with angular.

Comment: i strongly suggest u to use momentjs library to do stuffs like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use momentjs library . u can convert it like this :

```
var convertedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it in Angular using [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

`{{ today | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}`

Or

```
<input name="startDate" type="date" formControlName="startDate" [ngModel]="startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" />
```

Comment: isn't pipe just for displaying data only ? I need to change the date itself to yyyy-mm-dd so I can put it into my formcontrol and it will be show up in <input type="date" formControlName="startDate"/>

Comment: It will display the date in the required format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0):

To format the date returned from the SQL Server in the view to do so as follows:

```
{{ YourDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

For more formatting style: [Angular DataPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

To bind the date returned from the SQL Server to the input field with your desired format, you need to do so:

**In the Component**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
selector: 'your-html-template',
templateUrl: './your-html-template.html',
styleUrls: ['./your-html-template.css'],
providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {

 const yourDate = this.datePipe.transform(dateReturnedFromTheServer, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

 // bind that formatted date to your form
}
```